# Find all records NOT in a many-to-many association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails 3 with ActiveRecord, I have 2 models (Users and Tasks). These models are linked together with a has_many :through association on another model, Assignments. How can I find all Tasks that are NOT associated to a particular user?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :tasks, :through => :assignments
end

class Tasks < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments
end

class Assignments < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :tasks
end
```

Comment: Are you really looking for a SQL answer? If not, perhaps you could consider removing that tag. Otherwise, I can give you the SQL to do this.

Comment: Seconding emtucifor's comment.  The SQL is trivial.  Do you want SQL?

Comment: It's not what I'd prefer, but I think that may be the only way to do it. So yes, I'll take the SQL.

Comment: The non-sql solution is pretty trivial too: `Task.all - user.tasks`

Comment: Or perhaps: `Task.where('id not in (?)', user.task_ids)`

Comment: Noodl, can you post your second one as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short 'n sweet:

```
Task.all - user.tasks
```

Avoid loading user tasks:

```
Task.where('id not in (?)', user.task_ids)
```

I couldn't figure out how to do it with an outer join in AR.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume you want those tasks without any associated user, rather than not associated to a user in particular.

```
Tasks.joins('left outer join assignments on assignments.task_id = tasks.id').where('assignments.* is null')
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be a left outer join?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, thanks noodl. I can't test anything out just now so shouldn't be guessing.

Comment: SQLite3 has a problem with wildcards, throwing `"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "*"`. The fragment `'assignments.id is null'` works. (Any field that should be non-null with associated records.)